# Unity 2017.1 UWP Build Failing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just downloaded Unity 2017 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. I previously had a unity game that I wanted to turn into an xbox game on my computer, but I needed a newer version of Unity (previously used Unity 5.5). I open the project in Unity 2017 and go to build settings then build as a UWP app. However, when I open the solution in visual studio 2017, the solution fails to build with the following error message.

[image: First error]

I've tried unchecking "Unity C# Projects", as well as a lot of combinations of build settings in Unity but this keeps happening. When I run a "Build and Run" in Unity, I get the following errors:

[image: Build and run error]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have VS 2017 15.3.3? If so you might need the patched Unity. You could download it [here](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases)

For Unity 2017 it will be "Patch 2017.1.0p5".